# How do Firestore writes done offline handle authentication state?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
Firestore.firestore().document("someCol/someDoc").updateData([
    "someField": FieldValue.delete()
]) { (error) in
    // returns nothing in the scenario described below
}
```

- The client is signed into Firebase Auth.
- The Firestore security rules require authentication to perform writes.
- The client is offline and performs a write operation.

If the client signs out of Auth before it comes back online, the write will not execute, as I would expect. I assume this is because the authentication credentials were not queued with the write operation when the client was offline. Can this be confirmed? However, I would expect the completion handler of this write operation to return an error, but it returns nothing. Why does it return nothing and is this the way it should behave?

Answer (score 0):

In a normal situation the Authentication SDK will try to refresh the auth credentials once the connection is restored, before it tries to commit the writes to Firestore.

If you explicitly sign the user out while offline, that refresh won't happen as you signed the user out, so your writes will indeed fail.

---

I'm not sure why you don't get an error in your completion handler, but it's hard to be certain of anything without seeing the exact flow of all three components: Firestore writes, user authentication state, and being online/offline. A repro in a site like jsbin/stackblitz might be the easiest way to share that in a minimal form.

Comment: The flow is exactly as I described it. You can take any Firebase project with these Firestore security rules and execute a write immediately followed by a sign-out and you will see this behavior (unless if it is specific to the Swift SDK). What's also interesting is that if you never go offline--if you make the write and on the next line of code sign out--the write is made on the server (as expected) but the completion handler is not called. I'm trying to determine if this is a bug specific to the Swift SDK or the intended behavior of the framework. Can you confirm this behavior on your end?

Comment: "Can you confirm this behavior on your end?" If you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I can easily copy/paste to reproduce the behavior, I'll give it a try. Without that, the best I can do is describe the expected system behavior as I did in the first half of my answer.